# Creating anchors for footnotes in markdown

Tags: regex, markdown, jekyll, atom-editor

I help publish articles on history, archeology, toponymy, etc. The texts are scientific and they always have a lot of references to the literature used (anchors). The engine is jekyll, so I make everything through markdown.
Link text might look like this:

```
[12]
[5, 7, 13]
```

After processing, I bring them to this form:

```
[[12]](#t53-[12])
[[5, 7, 13]](#t53-[5])
```

To do this, I put together the following regular expression (I use atom.io, but it's not important):

find:

```
(\[[0-9, ]+\])
```

replace:

```
[$1](#t53-$1)
```

that is, in "complex" footnotes, I manually correct the link (but not its text).
t53 is an arbitrary text, chapter number, for example

What should be added to the regular expression so that after the replacement the link leads to the first source of literature?

Comment: Not a question one can asnwer without knowing where the "sources of literature" reside. Is it a separate file? I am not sure the jekyll tag is appropriate for this

Comment: Literature sources are at the very end of each essay.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a precise answer without a sample page that describes exactly what you want to achieve. To link to an internal anchor the syntax is something like `<a href="#t1-blah">link text</a>`. I am not sure how this would work in markdown, but you have the option of using straight HTML so try this:

```
<a href="#t53-$1">$1</a>
```

If it doesn't work or this is not what you want, I suggest you provide us with a short sample of your page and how you want it to change

Comment: for example [here](https://viktor-dnk.ru/toponymy/tenginka/). here in the very first paragraph is a "complex" anchor. and in the next paragraph "usual". [Here](https://github.com/viktor-dnk/viktor-dnk.github.io/blob/master/_toponymy/2022-04-27-tenginka.md) is a link to the source code of the page.